# How to sum a variable by group with NA?

Tags: r, statistics

I have a large data set like this :

```
ID    Number
153    31
       28
       31
       30
104    31
       30
254    31
266    31
```

and I want to compute sum by ID include the NA. I mean get this :

```
    ID   Number
    153   120
    104   61
    254   31
    266   31
```

I tried `aggregate` but I dont get the expected result. Some help would be appreciated

Comment: Well, after filling the NAs, aggregation is straightforward I guess. I reopened nonetheless.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

One option is to convert the blanks to `NA`, then `fill` replace the NA elements with non-NA adjacent elements above in 'ID', grouped by 'ID', get the `sum` of 'Number'

```
library(tidyverse)
df1 %>% 
  mutate(ID = na_if(ID, "")) %>% 
  fill(ID) %>% 
  group_by(ID) %>% 
  summarise(Number = sum(Number))
# A tibble: 4 x 2
#  ID    Number
#  <chr>  <int>
#1 104       61
#2 153      120
#3 254       31
#4 266       31
```

---

Or without using `fill`, create a grouping variable with a logical expression and `cumsum`, and then do the `sum`

```
df1 %>% 
  group_by(grp = cumsum(ID != "")) %>% 
  summarise(ID = first(ID), Number = sum(Number)) %>% 
  select(-grp)
```

#### data

```
df1 <- structure(list(ID = c("153", "", "", "", "104", "", "254", "266"
 ), Number = c(31L, 28L, 31L, 30L, 31L, 30L, 31L, 31L)), row.names = c(NA, 
 -8L), class = "data.frame")
```

Answer (score 1):

Or do it straightforwardly :) by

```
cbind(df1[df1$ID != "", "ID", drop = FALSE], 
      Number = rev(diff(c(0, rev((rev(cumsum(rev(df1$Number)))[df1$ID != ""]))))))
```